# Azure Blob Storage across serval Data Centers

Tags: azure, replication, cdn, azure-blob-storage

Say I've a Blob Storage in Amsterdam and someone from China is accessing it, uploading a file for example.

**My question:**

1. Does he need to send the file to Amsterdam or to his nearest Data Center ?
2. If the answer to 1 is that he need to send the file all the way to Amsterdam, how can I make the Blob Storage more accessible to him (the guy from China) ?

Comment: Unfortunately, your question doesn't fit on StackOverflow, as you're asking for opinions around optimal solution (and there's no single right answer to this). How you optimize is up to you: whether people from around the globe upload to a single place, or if you scale your app to run in different regions (but then do you just scale the web/app tier? Do you replicate blob storage in multiple regions?). These are architectural / cost questions you'll need to think through further, based on your app's needs.

Comment: @DavidMakogon instead of looking for a reason not to answer me question, try to see what I'm trying to understand with this question.
Any way I edit my question to two question if you feel like it answer if not its ok but stop trying to close my question, i need an answer.

Comment: Ron - you can "need an answer" all you want. But opinion-based, broad, open-ended questions are simply off-topic here. And I don't have the power to close your question. Heck - I even gave suggestions in my comment (which I won't post as an answer, as they aren't answers).

Answer (score 0):

You can upload to Blob Storage from any region. However, you should consider enabling Azure CDN on your Storage account. This will cache the blob at the CDN endpoint closest to the location from which the request was made.

Map of CDN locations: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cdn-pop-locations/